# how to pass stored values in list from one class to other class without duplication in java

Tags: java

I have one list of class type, named storeValues declared as:

```
private List<Myclass> storeValues = new ArrayList<Myclass>();
```

and a variable of same class type named selected declared as:

```
private Myclass selected;
```

and i am saving them before deleting them(requirement) as:

```
public String deleteAction() {
    saveValues(selected);
    fillRows.remove(selected);
    return null;
} 

//saveValues Function

public List<Myclass> saveValues(Myclass selected)
{  

    storeValues.add(selected);   
    return storeValues;  

}
```

Now i want all these values that are stored in this list(storeValues) in some other class. how can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your class architecture. You have basically three options:

1. from this class call a setStoreValues(List) in the other class
2. add a List getStoreValues() to this class and call it from the other class
3. call both methods from a third class

Comment: actually the scenario is like all these codes are in suppose Mainclass  and Myclass is a helper class and i want the values stored in this list in some Thirdclass.

Comment: sounds like You want the 3rd option

Answer (score 0):

In java objects are passed by reference, so just return storeValues. If you don´t want external object to modify it, you have to either pass a copy or wrap it into an unmodifiable list proxy — `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(storeValues)`. It wraps a list into a thin read-only accessor class without copying the contents of the underlying list.

Comment: If you don´t want external object to modify it, you have to either pass a copy or wrap it into an unmodifiable list proxy??? pls explain..

Comment: @curious See java.util.CollectionUtils class API.

Comment: It's java.util.Collections. Not collectionUtils. Use Collections.unmodifiableList(storeValues).

Comment: @JBNizet Of course. Thanks for correcting. I shouldn't answer questions from a phone that can handle one page at a time :) I confused it with Apache Commons CollectionUtils.

Comment: actually the scenario is like all these codes are in suppose Mainclass and Myclass is a helper class and i want the values stored in this list in some Thirdclass.